# calculate an serie

Tags: real-analysis

we have the fllowing formulate 
$$
y(x)= y_0(x)+ \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (y_{n+1}(x)-y_n(x))
$$
My question is how we deduce that 
$$
y(x)-y_n(x)= \sum_{j=n}^{+\infty} (y_{j+1}(x)-y_j(x)
$$?
i try to write all termes of the sum 
$$
y(x)= y_0(x)+ y_1(x) - y_0(x) + y_2(x) -y_1(x) +....+y_{m+1}(x)-y_m(x) ..
$$
but i don't find the second formula
Thank you in advance to the help

Comment: What have you done on this?

Comment: i edit my post. i try to write all the terms of the first formula, but i don't find the second formula

Comment: Don't you see how the terms cancel?  You have a $y_0$ and a $-y_0$ a $y_1$ and a $-y_1$ and so on.

Comment: yes i try it! But i don't find the second formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple . If you have the above identity with $j$ starting from zero(see the summation formula) then just substitute $n$ in place of zero you will get the answer.

Comment: Just follow the pattern no need of expansion

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand, i write what i try in my first post, but i don't found the second formula

Comment: What you are given is an identity .

Comment: See you are given an identity with n starting from 0 and in second case the summation is starting from n .

Comment: Now see in first formula where zeroes are there just replace those zeroes with n and you will be getting answer.

Comment: but how we can replace $0$ with $n$? is it possible to replace $0$ with $n$?

Comment: We can replace because your equation is an identity

Comment: It is true for all values of natural numbers

Comment: Did you understand

Comment: If my reasoning is helpful please do upvote

Comment: No i don't understand, sorry. My identity is true with $y_0$ where disparate the terms $y_{0},....,y_{n-1}$ when we replace $y_0 by $y_n$? Please